# How to create ASP .NET Core application for TargetFramework net5.0 and above in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-5

I am developing a web server application with (asp) .net 5 and VisualStudio 2019.
The TargetFramework in all .csproj files is set to `net5.0-windows`.
Now I want the application to run also with .net 6 (without .net 5 installed). But I can't do a Visual Studio update to VS2022 at the moment.
When I start the current (compiled for .net 5) version on a system with only .net 6 installed, I get an error message from the .net Runtime:

```
Description: A .NET application failed.
...
Message: You must install or update .NET to run this application.
...
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64)
```

Which seems logical, because in the .csproj file only the TargetFramework net5.0-windows is explicitly specified.

If I change the entry in the .csproj file to:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

I get a compiler error:

```
Error NETSDK1045 The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0. Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.
```

Which is also logical, since the studio/compiler does not know version 6.0.

Is there any way to compile the application to run with frameworks net5.0 **and above** without having to explicitly specify the "above" ones?

Comment: You don't need to do a Visual Studio update to install the .NET 6 SDK. However, it is worrying that you can't do a VS update too.

Comment: How are you running the app on the other system

Comment: @DavidG I thought .net 6 is not supported in VS2019. Or not recommended ... As for the VS update: of course I will update that soon, but right now I need to get some stuff done. So I don't want to touch my running system yet ...

Comment: @DanielA.White It is (installed and) run as a windows service.